# Recuperar valores de checkboxes geradas dinamicamente

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli, bootstrap-3

Eu tenho um form que tem tem alguns checkboxes com nomes de cidades que são geradas dinamicamente pelo PHP. Eu gostaria de saber como pegar esses valores e em que tipo de estrutura os armazenar(Array?) e em qual tipo de dados salvar no MySQL. Essas checkboxes que vão ser selecionadas na hora do cadastro do usuário e deverão dar ao mesmo permissões para acessar dados dessa determinada cidade. Então, alguma sugestão? Agradeço à quem puder me ajudar.

**Aqui está o código do form de cadastro**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        CADASTRAR USUÁRIO
    </div><br>

    <div id="filtros" style="padding-left: 20px">
        <a id="voltar_pagina" href="menu.php" class="btn btn-primary" title="Voltar ao início">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
        </a>
        <a id="voltar_lista" href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-primary" title="Voltar">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>                        
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">

        <form id="form_cad_usuario" data-toggle="validator" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="../config/usuario/processa_cad_usuario.php">

            <!--DADOS DO USUÁRIO-->
            <div class="page-header">
                <h4>Dados do Usuário</h4s>
                <hr>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">                 
                <label for="status_check" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ativo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input id="status_check" name="status_check" type="checkbox" value="ativo" checked>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nome_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_usuario" name="nome_usuario" placeholder="Nome" data-error="Por favor, informe o nome completo para o usuário." required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--DADOS DE ACESSO-->
            <div class="page-header">
                <h4>Dados de Acesso</h4>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuário</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_usuario" name="login_usuario" placeholder="Usuário" data-error="Por favor, digite um nome para o usuário." required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="senha_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Senha</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha_usuario" name="senha_usuario" placeholder="Senha" data-error="Por favor, digite um senha para o usuário." required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="permissao_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Senha</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="permissao_usuario" name="permissao_usuario" data-error="Por favor, selecione um nível de permissão para o usuário." required>
                        <option value="4">Jogos</option>
                        <option value="3">Regional</option>
                        <option value="2">Administrador</option>
                        <option value="1">Master</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--DADOS DA  REGIONAL-->
            <div class="page-header">
                <h4>Regionais Permitidas</h4>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <?php
            $resultado = lista_regionais();

            while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) 
            {
                $id_regional = $registro['id'];
                $nome_regional = $registro['nome'];

            ?>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <label class="col-md-10" for="<?php echo"regional_$id_regional" ?>">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo"regional[$id_regional]"; ?>" id="<?php echo"regional_$id_regional" ?>" value="<?php echo $nome_regional; ?>"> 
                                    <small><?php echo $nome_regional; ?></small>
                                </label>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            }
            ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button id="botao_salvar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Salvar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Aqui está o código da classe que processa o cadastro**

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once ('../seguranca.php');
include_once ('../../dao/usuario_dao.php');

verifica_acesso();

$nome = $_POST['nome_usuario'];
$login = $_POST['login_usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha_usuario'];
$permissao_str = $_POST['permissao_usuario'];
$check_status = $_POST['status_check'];

//Verifica o status recebido
if(!strcmp($check_status, "ativo"))
{
    $flag_ativo = 1;
}

//Verifica a permissão recebida
if(!strcmp($permissao_str, "4"))
{
    $permissao = 4;
}
else if(!strcmp($permissao_str, "3"))
{
    $permissao = 3;
}
else if(!strcmp($permissao_str, "2"))
{
    $permissao = 2;
}
else if(!strcmp($permissao_str, "1"))
{
    $permissao = 1;
}

var_dump($permissao);

//cadastra_usuario($nome, $login, $senha, $permissao, $flag_ativo, $modificado);
```

Como sou iniciante aceito também sugestões para melhorar a estrutura do código e a maneira como tudo está sendo feito. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No PHP você obtém os valores de um checkbox múltiplo da mesma maneira que obtém um checkbox normal. A diferença é que ele retorná um array.

No seu caso, se você imprimir a variável `$_POST['regional']`, observará que ela é um array.

```
$regional = $_POST['regional'];
print_r($regional);
```

Em relação ao armazenamento no banco de dados MySQL, sugiro criar uma tabela que ficará responsável por associar as regionais de cada usuário. Exemplo de estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario_regional (
  `id_usuario` int, 
  `id_regional` int
);
```

Com isso, ao cadastrar o usuário (inserir na sua tabela de usuário), você deve também inserir nessa tabela (`usuario_regional`) cada regional que o usuário está associado. Exemplo:

```
-- associada o usuário com ID=1 as regionais com ID=1, ID=2 e ID=3
INSERT INTO usuario_regional (`id_usuario`, `id_regional`)
VALUES (1, 1),
       (1, 2),
       (1, 3);
```

Comment: Agradeço bastante você ter tirado um tempinho pra me responder. Me corrija se eu estiver errado mas essa relação entre usuário e regional caracteriza uma relação MxN, não é? Eu sou um tanto leigo em banco de dados e estou tentando aprender à medida da necessidade. Você poderia, por favor, exemplifica uma query onde eu insiro o usuário no banco e também insiro os dados da regional nessa tabela? Se não for abusar demais gostaria de ver também como recuperar do banco as cidades para quais o usuário "x" tem acesso. Agradeço imensamente desde já. Abraço!

Comment: Essa é uma relação muitos-para-muitos (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_para_N).

Comment: Você de fazer duas query`s para realizar essa rotina: uma para inserir o usuário na tabela de usuários e outra para inserir na tabela de relacionamento (como exemplifiquei na resposta acima). Como no seu código você chama uma função chamada "cadastra_usuario", acredito que você já tenha nessa função uma query para inserir o usuário na tabela de usuários, então basta adicionar a query que insere na tabela de relacionamento "usuario_regional". Dica: utilize a função "mysqli_insert_id" do PHP para obter o ID do usuário inserido.